# How to replace login in "to" mail field?

Tags: emails

In registration notify email, or in emails sending by rules f.e., there is a prefix contained login of recipient in field "to". How can i change it for custom field value?
P.S. I use MimeMail module, if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to fill 'to' field in a format 'custom name ', instead 'address@mail.com'.